# What are all possible values for use with SPUrl?

Tags: spurl

So I've discovered:
$SPUrl:~SiteCollection
$SPUrl:~Site
~language (e.g. $SPUrl:~Site/yadda/~language/yadda or whatever)

Where can I find a comprehensive listing of what's available for use with $SPUrl?  And are there other prefixes like $SPUrl that can be used?

Comment: http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/urlaction-tokens-of-the-customaction-feature/ gives some more, but it's just odd there's no microsoft page with this information.

Answer (score 15):

I have not seen this documented anywhere. The ones I am aware of in SharePoint 2010 (from exploration) are:

~site/ : SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl

~sitecollection/ : SPContext.Current.Site.ServerRelativeUrl

{ItemId} : item.ID.ToString() (or item["BdcIdentity"] if external list)

{ItemUrl} : item.Url

{SiteUrl} : web.Url

{ListId} : list.ID.ToString(“B”)

{ListUrlDir} : list.RootFolder.Url

{RecurrenceId} : item.RecurrenceID

{Source} : Request URL

The usual caveats apply: if it is not documented, there is no guarantee it will still work in the next version or service pack.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe old, but here is the current documented URLs and Tokens
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think only ~sitecollection, ~site and ~language are supported by the SPUrl expression builder.